# new operator with parentheses "(", ")" instead of brackets "[", "]"

Tags: c++

I found a crazy mistake in my code.

I had written the following line:

```
GLfloat* points = new GLfloat(1024);
```

rather than

```
GLfloat* points = new GLfloat[1024];
```

I only just noticed it. My code has compiled and run a few times before I noticed the error. I realize that this is by fluke, but my question is what does the line I originally had do?

I notice that it looks kind of like the creation of a class using a pointer to allocated memory. Does it create a single GLfloat on the heap with the initial value of `1024.0`? If this is true, why is it valid syntax? (GLfloat is not a class, is it?)

Comment: Constructor call or value initialization when it comes to built-in types.

Comment: Value initialisation: http://codepad.org/KDPyKSMG

Comment: It's valid because why shouldn't it be? `new` isn't only for classes.

Comment: That's what you get for using `new[]`... :)

Comment: @ChristianHackl What's the alternative? Malloc?

Comment: @user3728501: `std::vector`.

Comment: @ChristianHackl often not suitable for embedded applications

Comment: @user3728501: If `std::vector` is not suitable for whatever environment, then `new[]` (or `new`) and `malloc` are not suitable there, either. The default allocator of the standard containers uses the heap just like `new` and `malloc` (but likely in a better way than any self-written container mechanism based on manual calls to `new` or `malloc` would). If you need a replacement for static arrays, use `std::array` or `boost::array`.

Comment: @ChristianHackl The standard library may not be fully implemented on the system. Dynamic memory may also not be implemented, however it is probably more likely that a method of dynamic allocation is available than std::vector.

Comment: @user3728501: I thought that such systems were becoming more and more a thing of the past. Anyway, some interesting past SO discussions about this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226252/embedded-c-to-use-stl-or-not / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853382/stl-in-embedded-enviornment

Comment: @ChristianHackl At home they are becoming a thing of the past, as e.g. RasbPi can be more powerful than a laptop was not so long ago. But you're forgetting infrastructure and enterprise applications that use older hardware by necessity for various reasons, also low-power stuff.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`GLfloat` is an OpenGL alias for `float` (i.e., `typedef float GLfloat;`). Consequently the code:

```
GLfloat* points = new GLfloat(1024);
```

Is equivalent to:

```
float* points = new float(1024);
```

Which allocates a floating point number and initializes it to `1024.0` and assigns its address to pointer `points`.

Comment: Why using literal double `1024.0` instead of literal float `1024.0f` (whereas the original is literal int `1024`) ?

Comment: @Jarod42 In `float(1024)` literal `int` is implicitly convert to `1024.0f`. I'm using `1024.0` to signify the value that is going to be assigned to the allocated `float`, is this confusing?

Comment: Not confusing, just strange to introduce an other type which also implicitly convert to `1024.f`. But it is just a detail.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you are creating a single `GLFloat` on the heap initialized to 1024.0. You can initialize primitives with the same syntax as classes. e.g.

```
int i(10);
```

Would create an int on the stack initialized to 10.

Answer (score 5):

> > what does the line I originally had do?

```
 GLfloat* points = new GLfloat(1024);
```

Let us try to replace `GLfloat` with `int`, you will see that if `GLFloat` is a type similar to `int` or `float`, then you will have the following:

```
int * points = new int(1024);
```

The above statement means that you are creating a pointer to an `int` with initial value being `1024`. So in your case, it means creating a pointer `points` to a variable with type being `GLfloat` and initial value as `1024`.

It is equivalent to write the following in a condensed version:

```
int * points = new int;
*points = 1024;
```

See [here](http://www.dcs.bbk.ac.uk/~roger/cpp/week9.htm) for more explanation.